# Extend gcdwebserver to Support HTTPS

Tags: gcdwebserver

I'm looking for an embeddable IOS web server that supports HTTPS.

Has anyone attempted to extend gcdwebserver to support SSL?
Or has anyone got specific advice on how to go about it?